# mpv player: combining mouse button and wheel?

Tags: media, mpv-media-player

Trying to use right click + mousewheel to up the volume, but it doesnt seem to work? Not possible?

```
MBTN_RIGHT+WHEEL_UP add volume 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not implemented yet and an open feature-request.

See [Wheel action when mouse button down (ie mbtn_right+wheel_up add volume +5) #9827](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/issues/9827)